# Unable to upgrade platform version on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Currently my workload is running on "Tomcat 8.5 with Java 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/3.3.9" and want to upgrade to Amazon Linux 2 and run my workload on "Tomcat 8.5 with Corretto 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/4.2.5". For testing was trying to clone the existing environment but don't see an option to upgrade the platform. The platform option is greyed out. Is this by design or am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation. I thought it will be an easy win by just cloning the environment and changing the Platform, but looks like the effort is much more. For now I have creating these environments manually. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this by design or am i doing something wrong ?

Its by design and you have to do it **manually**. The reason is that EB platforms based on Amazon Linux (AL1) are incomtabile with those based on AL2. This means that there is no automated procedure for the upgrade. You have to follow the AWS docs to do manual upgrade:

- [Migrating your Elastic Beanstalk Linux application to Amazon Linux 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.migration-al.html)